# Search text string in one cell to match another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I been searching and trying different commands like vlookup and power query but I can't seem to get the results I need.

Basically I have 2 columns. One just a single word text (column A) and the other with a string of text, sentence length (column B)

I just need to know if column A1 matches with anything in the next cell to it to column B1 and to say if it the match is true or not in column C.

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1,1))
```

Paste this in cell C1